# Electron setTimeout returns number in renderer process instead of Timeout object

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, settimeout

I have noticed that **in a renderer process of Electron**, `setTimeout` node function returns a `number` (integer) instead of a `Timeout` Object.

In main process, it returns the expected `Timeout` object

I use last version (i.e. `4.0.5`).

.

console of the renderer process :

[image]

console of main process :

```
npm start

> electron-timer-bug@0.0.1 start /home/doom/Documents/projets/testElectron/electron-timer-bug
> electron .

/home/doom/Documents/projets/testElectron/electron-timer-bug/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /home/doom/Documents/projets/testElectron/electron-timer-bug/node_modules/electron/dist/electron)
/home/doom/Documents/projets/testElectron/electron-timer-bug/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /home/doom/Documents/projets/testElectron/electron-timer-bug/node_modules/electron/dist/electron)
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 86: unknown element "blank"
mainWatchdog :  Timeout {
  _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 1000,
  _idlePrev:
   TimersList {
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     _unrefed: false,
     msecs: 1000,
     _timer: Timer { _list: [Circular] } },
  _idleNext:
   TimersList {
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     _unrefed: false,
     msecs: 1000,
     _timer: Timer { _list: [Circular] } },
  _idleStart: 648,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: null,
  _destroyed: false,
  [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 7,
  [Symbol(triggerId)]: 5 }
typeof(mainWatchdog) :  object
mainWatchdog.constructor.name:  Timeout
main callback
```

It is the same with or without nodeIntegration.

Here is the testing repo : https://gitlab.com/doom-fr/electron-timer-bug

Is it normal ? What's going wrong ?

Doom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a **renderer process**, [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) or [window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) is a Web API function which returns an integer:

> Return value
>
> The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies
> the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be
> passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.

Whereas in the **main process**, [setTimeout()](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_settimeout_callback_delay_args) is a Node.js *global object* method (described in [Timers](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args)) which returns a [Timeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout) object:

> setTimeout(callback, delay[, ...args])
>
> - *callback*  The function to call when the timer elapses.
> - *delay*  The number of milliseconds to wait before calling the callback.
> - *...args*  Optional arguments to pass when the callback is called.
>
> Returns: <Timeout> for use with clearTimeout()

In order to call the Node.js method from the *renderer process*, you would have to use Electron's remote [getGlobal](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#remotegetglobalname) method; for instance:

```
require('electron').remote.getGlobal('setTimeout')(() => { console.log('done'); }, 2000);
```